# Wordpress widget which displays archive tree

Tags: plugin-recommendation, archives

I'm a complete newbie, so would appreciate some help. Is there a wordpress plugin that can display all posts/archives as a part of a tree structure?

With high-level parents being `year` and children being `month`

Something like this,

```
-2012
---Jan
---Feb
---Mar
.
.
.
.
-2011
---Jan
---Feb
---Mar
..
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're a beginner I would like to mention that WordPress already has an archive widget.

If ever it does not suit your needs, You can browse through the available [archive plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=archive) at wordpress.org and choose which one is the best for you.